# What tokens are permitted as arguments to #include?

Tags: c++, c

What sort of tokens are required to be allowed by the standard in includes? E.g., are spaces in file names allowed?

Comment: All is "implementation defined". `standard has a "minimum"` I do not understand, what is a "minimum"? Standard defines that some names when used in `#include` will make specified symbols "visible". It doesn't mean that a folder or a file with that name exists.

Comment: @KamilCuk The standard has a "minimum" (like allowing `<type_traits>`, or `experimental/`). I want to know that minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From cppreference on [Source file inclusion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include)

> Any preprocessing tokens (macro constants or expressions) are
> permitted as arguments to #include and __has_include (since C++17) as
> long as they expand to a sequence of characters surrounded by < > or "".

Then in Explanation

> Searches for the file in **implementation-defined manner**. The intent of
> this syntax is to search for the files that are not controlled by the
> implementation.

Furthermore, [the c++20 final working draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) **5.8 Header names [lex.header]** and 
[ISO/IEC 9899:1999](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) **6.4.7 Header names** except newline, `>` and `"`.

```
header-name:
    < h-char-sequence >
    " q-char-sequence "
h-char-sequence :
    h-char
    h-char-sequence h-char
h-char:
    any member of the source character set except new-line and >
q-char-sequence :
    q-char
    q-char-sequence q-char
q-char:
    any member of the source character set except new-line and "
```

Comment: "any member of the **source character set** except new-line and (varies)" this is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is for C, with correct citations and quotes. It does not cover C++.)

C 2018 6.10.2 paragraphs 2 to 4 say:

> 2 A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> **# include <** *h-char-sequence* > *new-line*
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the **<** and **>** delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.
>
> 3 A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> **# include "** *q-char-sequence* **"** *new-line*
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the **"** delimiters. The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>
> **# include <** *h-char-sequence* **>** *new-line*
>
> with the identical contained sequence (including > characters, if any) from the original directive.
>
> 4 A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> **# include** *pp-tokens* *new-line*
>
> (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. The preprocessing tokens after include in the directive are processed just as in normal text. (Each identifier currently defined as a macro name is replaced by its replacement list of preprocessing tokens.) The directive resulting after all replacements shall match one of the two previous forms. The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a **<** and a **>** preprocessing token pair or a pair of **"** characters is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined.

The grammar symbols *h-char-sequence* and *q-char-sequence* are defined in 6.4.7. An *h-char-sequence* is **<** followed by any members of the source character set (at least one) other than new-line or **>** and then terminated by a **>**. A *q-char-sequence** is the same with **<** and **>** replaced by **"**. However, the behavior is undefined if the characters **'**, **\**, **//**, or **/*** appear in either sequence or if **"** appears in an *h-char-sequence*.